# Passing struct to function in C++

Tags: c++, struct, parameter-passing

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

float distance(tocki *A, tocki *B);

int main()
{
    struct tocki{
        int x, y;
    };

    tocki A, B, C;

    cout << "x = ";
    cin >> A.x;
    cout << "y = ";
    cin >> A.y;

    cout << "x = ";
    cin >> B.x;
    cout << "y = ";
    cin >> B.y;

    cout << "x = ";
    cin >> C.x;
    cout << "y = ";
    cin >> C.y;

    cout << distance(&A, &B);

    return 0;
}

//distance between (x1,y1) i (x2,y2) e  d = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 - (y2-y1)^2);

float distance(tocki *A, tocki *B){
    return sqrt(pow(A.y - A.x, 2) - pow(B.y - B.x, 2));
}
```

The errors I'm getting are:

```
'tocki' was not declared in this scope
'A' was not declared in this scope
'tocki' was not declared in this scope
'B' was not declared in this scope
```

On this line:

```
float distance(tocki *A, tocki *B);
```

So, what exactly am I doing wrong here? I want to pass a struct to function and get the result of the function in my main() program.

Comment: Move your definition of `tocki` above the first line that references it.

Comment: Careful, there's already a `distance` function in `std`, which you've imported the entirety of into the same scope as your own `distance`.

Comment: Now I'm getting this error : `error: request for member 'y' in 'A', which is of non-class type 'tocki*'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

place the toki struct outside the main function

Comment: strictly speaking, before declaration of float distance(tocki *A, tocki *B);

Answer (score 1):

The struct tocki should be declared before the declaration of the function distance, so the compiler knows that the struct exists when check the type of the parameters. Moreover, you should use A->y ecc. , because you have passing a pointer to the struct.

Comment: Thanks, I already did that and it does work without errors, but all the results I'm getting are either 0 or nan. Any reason for that?

Comment: The problem is probably due to the parameter passed and the use of the type int. Please try to add a casting to float   sqrt(pow((float)A.y - A.x, 2) - pow((float)B.y - B.x, 2));

Comment: Nope, doesn't work.. I tried `(float)sqrt((float)pow((float)(A->y) - (float)(A->x), 2) - (float)pow((float)(B->y) - (float)(B->x), 2));`

Comment: Morever, you receive a NAN when the parameter of the sqrt function is negative :-)

Comment: Ok, I got this now : `(float)sqrt((float)pow((float)(B->x) - (float)(A->x), 2) - (float)pow((float)(B->y) - (float)(A->y), 2));` and it still doesn't work, I'm getting 0 as answer.

Comment: you are still using minus (-) to add the intermediate value of the two calling to the pow function... you should use plus (+)... you can also avoid to cast to float because the compiler make an implicit cast for you... simply cut and replace my code...  return sqrt(pow(A->x - B->x, 2) + pow(A->y - B->y, 2));

Comment: Doesn't work even with `sqrt(pow() + pow())`.